# How can I update node.js code that I got through npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

So I am relatively new with node.js, and I have a stupid question.

Like everyone, I have a ton of modules that I have installed through npm.

There is one module in particular that I would like to change and update on my own. I went into the one of their files and put in a simple console.log in a method that I know I am calling. My little console message didn't show which leads me to believe that I need to do something before I can update something in my node_modules directory.

Do I need to fork the module on github and get it out of the node_modules directory?

What am I missing?

Thanks,
David

Comment: What you have described doesn't sound wrong. Are you certain you are calling the correct function ?

Comment: As above, what you are doing sounds correct. However, it is worth noting that different modules may have different versions of the same library, so the code that is actually being called may nested elsewhere.

Comment: use some debugger, like node-inspector to see whats going on...

Comment: Also, depending on whether you installed locally or globally, or _both_, affects where you should be modifying.

Answer (score 0):

when you call a function from a module make sure you call the *require('moduleName')* function on top of your code first. Also if the function you are calling is inside a class, you need to call it like this:

```
require('moduleName');
var sample = new ClassName();
// call your function
ClassName.functionName();
```